# Search cell for list of characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell listing an arbitrary number of characters, e.g. `abc`. How do I detect, using an Excel formula, whether a given other cell contains one or more of these characters?

In the example below, the words that have a, b, or c in them return TRUE, while those that don't return FALSE. That's the desired output.

[image]

I know how to detect the presence of one character:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("a",B4)))
```

and, if I know for sure I have 3 characters, I can combine three of these `ISERROR` statements like this:

```
 =NOT(AND(ISERROR(SEARCH("a",B4)),ISERROR(SEARCH("b",B4)),ISERROR(SEARCH("c",B4))))
```

but how would you do this for an arbitrarily long list of characters, as given in cell A4?

Note that I am not looking for a VBA solution; I can already do that.

Comment: Not a complete solution, but may give a new avenue of thinking: `=OR(IFERROR(SEARCH({"a","b","c"},B4)>0,{FALSE,FALSE,FALSE}))` as an array formula. Now just need a way to split a string into an array of characters...

Comment: Right. Yours is same as the shorter `=NOT(AND(ISERROR(SEARCH({"a","b","c"},B4))))`

Comment: @chrisneilsen: Got it now. See answer. Thanks for leading the way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=NOT(AND(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID($A$4,
COLUMN(INDEX($1:$1,1):INDEX($1:$1,LEN($A$4))),1),$B4))))
```

Basically is an improved version of the formula posted by the OP that eliminates the use the volatile `OFFSET` function

Comment: Exactly... I was indeed concerned about using volatile `OFFSET`. I wasn't sure how to replace it with `INDEX`, but this is it.

Answer (score 2):

Got it!

```
=NOT(AND(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID($A$4,
    COLUMN($A$1:OFFSET($A$1,0,LEN($A$4)-1))-COLUMN($A$1)+1,1),$B4))))
```

or minor variation to shorten it a bit:

```
=NOT(AND(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID($A$4,
    COLUMN(OFFSET($A$1,0,0,1,LEN($A$4)))-COLUMN($A$1)+1,1),$B4))))
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>, and copied down.

[image]

This part

```
COLUMN($A$1:OFFSET($A$1,0,LEN($A$4)-1))-COLUMN($A$1)+1
```

is just a trick to return an array {1, 2, 3, ..., number or chars to search for}. In this example, {1,2,3,4,5}. The last bit

```
-COLUMN($A$1)+1
```

is to make sure this still works if someone inserts columns before column A (otherwise the array would no longer start at 1). Example still working when 4 columns added before A:

[image]

Instead of that last bit, @EEM suggests hard-coding the `$A$1` cell reference in a string and using `INDIRECT`, such that the cell reference stays fixed regardless of any columns inserted. The resulting formula is a bit longer, but works fine as well:

```
=NOT(AND(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID($C$4,
     COLUMN(INDIRECT("$a$1"):OFFSET(INDIRECT("$a$1"),0,LEN($C$4)-1)),1),$D4))))
```

Comment: The so called trick should be: `COLUMN($A$1:OFFSET($A$1,0,LEN(A$4)-1))`. This part is redundant `-COLUMN($A$1)+1` as matter of fact it returns zero.

Comment: @EEM: Sure it returns zero now, but what happens when someone inserts a column before column A? It screws up your formula. In fact that's what I started with (check out the edit summary if you want), and then realised the problem, so I fixed it to the way it is now.

Comment: Ok I see your argument but been that the case: what would you do if instead of one column, four columns are inserted? Hopefully by now you should realize that your solution does not address your concern. Suggest to use `INDIRECT` and btw still don't need the redundant part...

Comment: @EEM: Well, actually, it does also works [when 4 columns are inserted](http://i.stack.imgur.com/02elX.png). That's the whole point. Hopefully by now you should realize that testing a solution is a good thing to do before asserting it doesn't work.

Comment: @JeanFrançoisCorbett apologies somehow I was still thinking on the fixed "$A$1", didn't realized that it moves\changes with the insertion, and you are right I "always" test everything before, but then that time that negates the "always" then becomes a failure (murphy's law)... point taken. Coming back to the formula: this form makes redundant the last part: `COLUMN(OFFSET($1:$1,0,0,1,LEN($D$4)))`, by taking the entire row insertions and deletions of columns do not affect the reference to the row. This is what I was thinking about...

Comment: @EEM: Right, well, your answer is better; it's a minor change, but one that makes a whole lot of difference. Away with volatile functions. BTW, I don't know if you're the one who downvoted this answer (and question) but if so, hopefully this discussion removes the need for that.

Comment: Not only that I'll upvote it but you need to edit the question to allow the correction...

Comment: Done. Did you originally think the question sucked? And the answer? Why?

Comment: It seemed at that point another self answered questions with no purpose but to provide a self answer with no quality (that due to the nature of the answer...) However, at the same time I did give you the opportunity to explain yourself better by engaging in the discussion, which in time proved the entire opposite. The outcome an upvote. Btw thanks for reminding me of that…

Comment: Well, I take exception to the "no quality" epithet, but let's hope we all lighten up a little bit... BTW, self-answers are [encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Absolutely and I have no problem at all with self answers. They are encouraged and it's good when someone have been dealing with a situation which finally got it solved and it's more than welcome to share knowledge, I agree and encourage that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very pretty, but I have a solution if you know the maximum length your input string is going to be:

```
In Column H numbered list from 1 to [Max Length]

In G1 I entered =MID($A$4,H1,1) and copied down

In I1 I entered =IF(H1<=LEN($A$4),H1,"") and copied down
```

These can be copied down to as far as the max length of your input field will go

Then the formula in column C

```
{=IF(SUM(IFERROR(SEARCH(OFFSET($G$1,0,0,COUNT($I:$I),1),B4),0))>0,"TRUE","FALSE")}
```

entered as a range formula (ctrl+shift+enter)

The number in column H is used with the Mid function to split the letters out individually.
The offset in the main function uses the Count of numbers in column I to determine the size of the Range to look at in column G.

This can be tidied up somewhat but I figured it is easier to see my thinking when it is split out like this.